# Почему при скролле до якоря страницу смещает влево?

Tags: html, css, frontend, layout

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:
Если нажать на голубую кнопку по центру внизу экрана, а в открывшемся меню нажать "Обратная связь", то происходит скроллинг вниз до секции с формой. Страница при этом уходит влево и справа появляется белая полоса. Если полистать наверх, то видно, что выходят за границы блок с id='footer-form' и блок с id='why'...
А если сделать вышеописанное мной, а потом в Chrome DevTools удалить эти 2 блока, то страница возвращается в нормальное положение...

Почему так? Ведь я указал для html, body

```
{overflow-x: hidden !important;}
```

При этом если просто скроллить мышкой вниз, то всё нормально...
Вот ссылка: https://konstantinstepanyan.github.io/landing/

Благодарю за внимание..

Comment: потому что в footer-form margin-left: 20%; Поцизионируйте не footer-form, а содержимое внутри него.

Comment: Если совсем просто, то у footer-form убрать margin, создать внутри контейнер и в нем уже сделать тоже самое. Или без контейнера споцизиционировать красиво, без левого margin